# Can I use the code of /test/latency.c as reference to find the latency only from buffer to playback?

Tags: android, timestamp, latency, alsa

Since I only need the latency between the buffer and playback, for /test/latency.c (http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2latency_8c-example.html), it includes capture and playback, can I do revise this code as a reference to find only for playback? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to know what the driver thinks the latency is (in which case you just call `snd_pcm_delay`), or do you want to actually measure the latency (in which case you need to record the signal, which is not possible without getting the capture latency into the measurement)?

Comment: @CL. I would like to know how to actually measure the latency with that. But I am thinking about to preload a sound signal into the measurement but not capture......Can I achieve that? I mean can I achieve "preload first and then playback and then get the latency between buffer and the moment it playbacks"? Thank you

Comment: How would you measure a sound signal without capturing it? And what is your actual problem?

Comment: @CL. I am just wondering how to load a sound (maybe a music) into the buffer and then play it. In this piece of code, it measure the latency   between capture and playback. What I want to do here is that revise this code, try to get rid of the capturing part, only leave the part from buffer to play, load the sound into buffer and test the latency between buffer and play.    However, my problem is that can I achieve this process based on  /test/latency.c? If I can, how can I get rid of the capturing part?

Comment: @CL. If I have to keep the capture part, is there anyway I can do (any revision on /test/latency.c) to capture a sound signal and then only get the latency between the buffer and playback?

Comment: You could just try to divide the latency by two, but this won't be accurate. What you can measure in software is only the time when you stuff the playback samples into the device, and when you get the captured samples back. Anything that happens in between is, from the software's point of view, a black box.